# Logstash http module not sending message

Tags: windows, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to make an output POST message with the http module. I have the following config:

```
http {
        http_method => "post"
        url => "http://localhost:40104/api/message"
        format => "message"
        content_type => "application/json"
        message => "Test"
    }
```

It calls the API, but the POST has no body. I expect it to contain "Test".

We are using Logstash version 1.5 on Windows.

We tried using `as_json` after the message, we tried formatting the message as JSON, we tried sending `content_type` text and we tried a few other things.

Why does it not work and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this configuration I can get the message as raw body :

```
http {
  http_method => "post"
  url => "http://requestb.in/1mcpwx51"
  format => "message"
  content_type => "text/plain"
  message => "Test"
}
```

I suggest you could test your output with the http://requestb.in service, it's really useful to see what input your server will get on request.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We tried using text/plain as content type already. We suspect it is a bug in Logstash. Thanks for the requestb.in link, very useful.

Comment: But, this configuration works on my side, maybe you should check on your logstash setup.

Comment: I'm running it in Docker from this image : https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/logstash/ (running with java7-jre on ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: I suspect it is a bug on the Windows version. We have the exact same configuration as you.